# Why did this edit get attributed to the community user?

Tags: bug, edits, community-user

It seems that [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18205553/revisions) by the OP of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205553/facebook-share-code-issues) was attributed to the community user.

I'm assuming that the edit was by the OP from the edit summary:

> updated my question

and from the actual update. Both texts are speaking in the first person.

Comment: I think this is most likely [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. :)

Comment: @sha - it seems so. Using two browsers simultaneously where one is logged in and one is not is quite an edge case...

Comment: Not sure it's two browsers, maybe he logged out, closed the browser, came back to edit and forgot to log in.

Comment: More importantly, why did you not edit it further?

Answer (score 8):

As per suggested edit page https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2710826, it was suggested *"by an anonymous user"*.

It looks like the user updating his own question without being logged in the system.

Maybe he was using two browsers? One logged and the other one not. Suggested with the unlogged and then approved with the logged one.

Note that whenever an edit is suggested to your post, you get a notification and can review it. So the user wanted to edit his post and ended up reviewing his own edit suggestion... and of course approving it.

Comment: So the user reviewed his own edit... weirdness :P

Comment: @Lix well, he didn't get any reputation from this, just [one badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian?userid=1943271) and it's most likely he didn't even notice.